# spanish characters (ú, í ) changed to (Ã³ , Ã) on UI with Wicket and coded in Java

Tags: java, wicket

The wicket: message is not showing the Spanish character correctly. Instead of (ú, í) It shows (Ã³, Ã) or some other characters such as "?" on UI.

I have tried in HTML file: -

```
 <meta name="viewport" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1; text/html; charset=UTF-8 "  />
```

My Resource bundle are: `Class.properties, Class_es.properties, Class_de.properties.`

In web.xml I have used:- `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Properties file is also encoded in UTF-8 and using escape character "\uXXXX".

What else I should try. Please help

Comment: The `.properties` files are read using character set iso-8859-1. If you saved them as utf-8, they'll be read back incorrectly, as the utf-8 bytes will instead be mapped to iso-8859-1 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to rename `Class_es.properties` to `Class_es.utf8.properties` and write the text inside **without** the Unicode codes, i.e. use `ú` instead of `\uXXXX`.